# NodeJS server not accepting POST requests

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-ec2, postman

I have the following nodeJS server:

```
**
 * Created by daniel on 27/01/17.
 */
...
    var express = require('express');
...

    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('server-crt.pem'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem')
    }, app).listen(443);

    app.post('/', function(req, res){
        console.log("POSTED!!!!");
res.end("blahblahblah");



    });
```

I generated server-key.pem, server-crt.pem and ca-crt.pem using the following link:

https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2#.h0klo4fc1

I am running the server on an amazon EC2 instance.

I have moved the ca-crt to my client, and imported it into chrome. However, when I use Postman to send a POST request, my server does not receive it.

I have a NodeJS client running which can send POST requests successfully, it has the paramater process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED set to "0" as I could not get the SSL to work there, either.

How can I get either a) Postman to not care about SSL or b) chrome to use the certificate successfully? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to debug SSL verification issues. While it is better to make the certificate work, Postman can [disable SSL verification](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/ignoring_ssl).

Although it's for the (soon to be discontinued) Postman Chrome App, their site actually has instructions for various operating systems for [installing certificates for Chrome](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/28/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/) (and therefore Chrome add-ons).

Comment: I currently have Postman 4.9.3 installed on MacOS, and I do have the option.